# How Can I Read Image From SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I saved an image in SQL Server using a `MemoryStream`.

Now, I want to read all images from SQL Server and show them in `<a href="this is eath of images" >`

```
for (i = 0; i <=  dt.Rows.Count ; i++)
{
   Byte[] img = (Byte[])(reader["image"]);
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
   BinaryWriter imgforshow = new BinaryWriter(ms);
   ms.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
   div1.InnerHtml = div1.InnerHtml + "<a href='"+ imgforshow +"' runat=server data-   lightbox=roadtrip title=''>";
   div1.InnerHtml = div1.InnerHtml + "<img src='"+ imgforshow +"' width=100 height=140></a> ";
}
```

How can I show image in this lines?

```
 div1.InnerHtml = div1.InnerHtml + "<a href='"+ imgforshow +"'......
 div1.InnerHtml = div1.InnerHtml + "<img src='"+ imgforshow +"'.......
```

Comment: I did this _years_ ago by essentially creating an `Image.aspx` page which would serve the image bytes back and set appropriate headers so the browser would think it's receiving an image normally. That would require you though to have your `reader["image"]` context/state available to the `Image.aspx` page though. (EDIT: the HTML then would be `<img src="Image.aspx?ID=myImageID" />`) I suspect these many years later there might be a better option.

Comment: create a image dinamically and send to it?

Comment: You could go for an [IHttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090(v=vs.100).aspx), which does exactly the same as @ChrisSinclair's version.

Comment: i changed image to array of byte and store them in sql .but now i want to read byte array from sql and convert to image for show in my page. I've used the correct code???

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing an image handler that writes back your image. You could use something like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string id = context.Request.QueryString["id"];
    byte[] img = GetImage(id);
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; // change accordingly
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(img);
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.Response.Close();   
}
```

Note, based on your image type, you'll want to change the content type of your response. `GetImage` would return a byte array for an image with the specified `id`. You don't need to pass it to a MemoryStream.

Your SQL query would look something like this:

> SELECT image FROM images WHERE id = @id

```
try
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(connection);
    command.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    command.Parameters.Add("id", id);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // do something with the exception
}
```

There is another option that allows you to embed all images at once in your page, but it involves using data Uris which can slow down the loading of your page. First, you have to grab your image from your database as a byte array and then base64 encode the byte array.

```
byte[] img = GetImage(id);
string imageSource = "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," +  Convert.ToBase64String(img)  + " />";
```

This is not recommended for larger images as the page will wait until all images are downloaded before displaying any of them. Your users might get upset at perceived long wait times. It can work with smaller images though. Just be wise in how you serve the images. If they're several megabytes, I wouldn't use this method. Again, the mime type will need to be adjusted based on the image type.

Comment: You'd need to call this image handler for each image. I'm assuming that each image in your database has an ID associated with it? If so, you could do a `SELECT` query and limit the results with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: for examlpe: i have 4 image in sql,now how can i show all 4 image in only  one page. i want to create gallery page .

Answer (score 0):

Use server image control:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="img1" ImageUrl="getimage.ashx?id=1" />
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="img1" ImageUrl="getimage.ashx?id=2" />
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="img1" ImageUrl="getimage.ashx?id=3" />
```

AND Inside Handler:

```
string id = context.Request.QueryString["id"];
DataRow dr = GetImageById(id);
Byte[] myImg = (Byte[])dr["Image"];
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; 
context.Response.BinaryWrite(myImg);
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.Close();
```